# Is there a pg_try_advisory_lock timeout when locker lost connection?

Tags: postgresql

### Context

We have several machines accessing same PostgreSQL database for which we use `pg_try_advisory_lock` to avoid concurrent access for some commands, and there is just one issue that we can't see how to solve, it is when a session that got the lock lost its connection to the database (this is the case on Ethernet or WiFi connection lost for example) for an undefined amount of time.

With how advisory locks work in PostgreSQL, only the session that got the lock can unlock it, not even another session on same machine can, neither postgres user that has all rights. In this case then we have to way it unlocks itself, from what we have seen there is a 2 hours timeout.

### Question

Anyone knows if it is possible to modify the 2 hours timeout ? From what I've seen it seems not but maybe I missed something.

### (Edit) Manual workaround

After some search I finally find a way to manually release a lock without restarting server, that is with `pg_terminate_backend` but IT IS DANGEROUS since it releases any lock whether the session who has the lock is still alive or not:

- I acquired a lock from a machine with `SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(123456)`,
- From another one I checked it with `SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE locktype = 'advisory' AND objid = 123456` and noted the pid for this lock,
- Still from this another one I executed `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)` and lock was gone.

Answer (score 1):

An advisory lock gets removed when the database session ends *on the server*.

The problem that you observe happens when the client doesn't disconnect from the server, but the client process dies or is killed. Then the server uselessly keeps waiting for communication from the client, until the TCP keepalive system figures out the the client is no longer there.

You can change the TCP keepalive parameters in `postgresql.conf`:

```
tcp_keepalives_interval = 5
tcp_keepalives_count = 5
tcp_keepalives_idle = 60
```

That would make the connection and the lock go away at most 80 seconds after the client died.

For more details, you could read [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tcp-keepalive-for-a-better-postgresql-experience/).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately after change of these parameters, restart of PostgreSQL service it did not work, I got lock from a machine on which I then disconnected network more than an hour ago and the lock is still effective on the database.

Comment: Then the network connection is still up, or you have an operating system that has a problem with TCP keepalive.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the network interface is not up, I'm on a Linux on which I run `sudo service network stop` that makes its interface down, first confirmed with `ping psql-server-hostname` that answers `Temporary failure in name resolution` and confirmed again with `ip a` that lists `eth0` (its only physical interface) as down. Not sure though for the second one, PostgreSQL server is on Windows 10.

Comment: It should work on Linux and Windows. At least, it has always worked for me. Can you see the changed parameters with `SHOW ALL`?

Comment: Yes I see new values with `SHOW ALL`, also, yesterday I rebooted computer where PostgreSQL server is to ensure new values have been taken (I did not know how to check them).